# How do I show a post by selected tags in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to show a post by selected tags? I tried to do some research on Google, but I can't get it. I have faced this problem and I am stuck.

I have created a new WordPress post

ex.

> Lasagne and I tags it as Sweet-Food,Creamy-Food
>   Noodles and the tags = Spicy-Food,Sweet-Food

On the page I wanted to show the Sweet-Food tags and it will show Noodles and Lazagna.   Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible

```
function get_tags_post($tag_name)
{
    $original_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $brand_name= $tag_name;
    $args=array('posts_per_page'=>5, 'tag' => $brand_name);
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            echo '<li>';
            the_title();
            echo '</li>';
        endwhile;
    endif;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $original_query;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Pass the tag name in the variable $brand_name and you can get the post related to the tag

If you want to get the tag list you can achieve that from the below code

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags(); // gives you the list of all tags 
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo '<img src="http://example.com/images/' . $tag->term_id . '.jpg" 
alt="' . $tag->name . '" />'; 
  get_tags_post($tag->name); // pass the dynamic names to the function and it will return the post of the particular tag 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: by the way where to put..
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$brand_name= "Your tag";
$args=array('posts_per_page'=>5, 'tag' => $brand_name);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile;
endif;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
wp_reset_postdata();

Comment: And... it Show all the tags.. i want .. specific tags only

Comment: @pentashape for specific tag you need to pass the tag name in the $brand_name variable.

And the $original_query was to save the instance of the $wp_query and then assigned back.

Comment: If i wanted to use <?php single_tag_title(); ?> for the brand name? why cant

Comment: @pentashape Please accept the answer if my ans helped you to solve the issue :D

Comment: yes, but if i want to use <?php single_tag_title(); ?> .. how does it work @Veerendra

Comment: @pentashape I think you need to take the value from single_tag_title into a variable and then pass it you can get more about it on 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_tag_title

Comment: i dont understand.. much bout it

Comment: @pentashape You can just get the tag name from the url and can just pass into the $brand_name why to use single_tag_title and make more complex

Comment: @because i want to make the page for all my tag post.. if i use the branding.. i need to type it 1 by 1

Comment: @pentashape i have made changes in my answer to make it dynamic by making the function and calling it inside the loop to get the posts of tags dynamic and you don't need to type the tag name

Comment: It wont show the Post that i include the tag with ... No errors.. but it didn't show my post

Comment: @pentashape I am here to help you not to code for you please try something on your own do some google :)

Comment: i know, thank you for all the help.. but i am stuck at this point @veerendra.. I just wanted to creat it.. Sorry. for taking your time.. i just want to know.. how to do it